# repeater with postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a repeater, and each item has a check box and radio button.

- the checkbox disable all the controls inside the item when checked (with auto post back)
- the radio button display a popup once checked (also with auto post back).

The case is: if there is a radio button checked in any item of the repeater, the popup will display when I check the checkbox control to disable an item.  During the postback, a checked radio button will cause the popup to display.

How can I prevent this? Checkbox should only disable the item not to display the popup.

My code

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void rptr1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {


            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                Label lbl1 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_dg_task");
                Label lbl2 = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_dg_seq");
                CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkb_NO");
                RadioButton l1 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("L1");
                RadioButton l2 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("L2");
                RadioButton l3 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("L3");
                RadioButton l4 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("L4");
                RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("R1");
                RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("R2");
                RadioButton r3 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("R3");
                RadioButton r4 = (RadioButton)e.Item.FindControl("R4");
                AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender mpex = (AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)e.Item.FindControl("mpe1");

                if (l1.Checked)
                {
                    //pop.Enabled = true;
                    ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
                }


                if (chb.Checked == true)
                {

                    l1.Enabled = false;
                    l2.Enabled = false;
                    l3.Enabled = false;
                    l4.Enabled = false;
                    r1.Enabled = false;
                    r2.Enabled = false;
                    r3.Enabled = false;
                    r4.Enabled = false;
                    lbl1.CssClass = "grayedout";
                    lbl2.CssClass = "grayedout";


                }
                else
                {
                    l1.Enabled = true;
                    l2.Enabled = true;
                    l3.Enabled = true;
                    l4.Enabled = true;
                    r1.Enabled = true;
                    r2.Enabled = true;
                    r3.Enabled = true;
                    r4.Enabled = true;
                    lbl1.CssClass = "seq";
                    lbl2.CssClass = "task";


                }
            }


        }


    protected void rptr1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptr1.Items)
            {
                if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
                {
                    CheckBox chb = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("chkb_NO");
                    Label lbl1 = (Label)item.FindControl("lbl_dg_task");
                    Label lbl2 = (Label)item.FindControl("lbl_dg_seq");
                    RadioButton l1 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("L1");
                    RadioButton l2 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("L2");
                    RadioButton l3 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("L3");
                    RadioButton l4 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("L4");
                    RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("R1");
                    RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("R2");
                    RadioButton r3 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("R3");
                    RadioButton r4 = (RadioButton)item.FindControl("R4");
                    AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender mpex = (AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupExtender)item.FindControl("ModalPopupExtender1");


                    if (chb.Checked == true)
                    {
                        l1.Enabled = false;
                        l2.Enabled = false;
                        l3.Enabled = false;
                        l4.Enabled = false;
                        r1.Enabled = false;
                        r2.Enabled = false;
                        r3.Enabled = false;
                        r4.Enabled = false;
                        l1.Checked = false;
                        lbl1.CssClass = "grayedout";
                        lbl2.CssClass = "grayedout";

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        l1.Enabled = true;
                        l2.Enabled = true;
                        l3.Enabled = true;
                        l4.Enabled = true;
                        r1.Enabled = true;
                        r2.Enabled = true;
                        r3.Enabled = true;
                        r4.Enabled = true;
                        lbl1.CssClass = "seq";
                        lbl2.CssClass = "task";


                    }

                    if (l1.Checked)
                    {

                        //pop.Enabled = true;
                        ModalPopupExtender1.Show();


                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should consider using the events as they are intended.  ItemDataBound to manipulate data before being displayed, PreRender to manipulate any objects after event handlers, and use event handlers to handle events.  You should consider using the repeaters ItemCommand to determine appropriate display logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the PreRender event to decide whether to show the popup, but use the OnCheckedChanged event of the radio button to show it.

```
l1.CheckedChanged = (sender, e) => { if (l1.Checked) ModalPopupExtender1.Show(); };
```

Comment: Many thanks, that solved the issue, but I had to create an event handler for the radio first and insert it in Page_Load event.

Comment: now another problem, I created another popup for l1 which works fine.

Comment: I have 2 radio groups (l1-l2-l3-l4) and (r1-r2-r3-r4), if check l1 the popup shows, then when I check r2 both popup shows up.

Comment: Sorry Amiram but I'm new to programing

Comment: Do you have different popup control for each radio button? If so, you have to hide the popup you showed before.

Comment: yes I have 2. I tried that but when I hide the other one it get hide forever, mean It will not show again when I check the other radios